# Random number in C with rand

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{




    int a = rand()%  36;
    int b = rand() % 36;
    int c = rand() % 36;
    int d = rand() % 36;

    printf("1 = %d\n" , a);
    printf("2 = %d\n" , b);
    printf("3 = %d\n" , c);
    printf("4 = %d\n" , d);




    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to write a c programe that can display random number from 1 to 36. The programe above and display random number from 1 to 36 only once. When I run the programe second time the random number stay the same. Is there something that is missing to have random nubmer each time a run the programme?

Answer (score 1):

You need to seed the random number generator using `srand()`. Otherwise, `1` is assumed to be the seed.

[`srand()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html) man page:

> If no seed value is provided, the rand() function is automatically
>   seeded with a value of 1.

That means everytime you run your program, the same seed (1) is used and this you'll always get the same sequence of numbers.

Typically, `srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));` is used for seeding. But if you run your program sufficiently quickly (i.e. if `time(NULL)` returns the the same value) then even with this, you might get the same sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `srand` and `time`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    int a = rand()%  36;
    int b = rand() % 36;
    int c = rand() % 36;
    int d = rand() % 36;

    printf("1 = %d\n" , a);
    printf("2 = %d\n" , b);
    printf("3 = %d\n" , c);
    printf("4 = %d\n" , d);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After `main` put in the line

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

To initialise the random number generator.

You will also need the #include for time

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of seeding. Random number generators have patterns when generating random numbers and thus need to be "seeded" before use. For non-security-related uses `rand()` is fine and it can be seeded with `time(null)`. For example:

```
srand ( time(NULL) );
int a = rand()%  36;
int b = rand() % 36;
int c = rand() % 36;
int d = rand() % 36;

printf("1 = %d\n" , a);
printf("2 = %d\n" , b);
printf("3 = %d\n" , c);
printf("4 = %d\n" , d);
```

**EDIT**: Also, to get numbers between 1 and 36, you should say: `(rand() % 36) + 1;`. `rand()` generates between 0 to *RAND_MAX*, so if you just mod by 36, you may get back zero, which is obviously not in the range of 1 to 36.

Comment: "Random number generators have patterns when generating random numbers and thus need to be "seeded" before use" - that's wrong for the general case.

Comment: @Olaf, oh, would you care to offer a correction or explanation as to how that is wrong? As far as I know, there are patterns to PRNGs, and they do need to be seeded before use in order to not have repeated outputs between runs. However, if you think otherwise, I would be interested in hearing your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: The 'P' in 'PRNG' is for "pseudo"... a PRNG's output is not really random, just apparently so (which is why you get the same sequence for the same seed).  Actual random number generators don't behave that way.  (However, `rand()` uses a PRNG).

Comment: Many prngs use some form of external entropy to generate numbers, such as `/dev/random`.  Your statement "before use" is also somewhat misleading, since there's nothing stopping a prng library which requires a seed from seeding itself when a seed isn't provided by the caller.

Comment: @SpencerDoak: You already pointed out the difference. And security is not the only application for RNGs; there are algorithms which require a uniform (or other shaped) distribution which a simple modulo can only guarantee under very specific constraints. For the standard PRNG, `% 36` will most probably fail.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian, in the case of `rand()`, however, no external entropy (such as `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`) is utilized. `rand()` simply uses a multiplicative congruential RNG, which thus makes it produce patterns if not seeded. Also, of course there is nothing stopping a PRNG library from seeding itself, but `rand()` does not. Hence, why it is best practice to seed it before use. As for the differences between PRNGs and other RNGs (namely CSPRNGs & TRNGs), as the OP is clearly a beginner, it is out of the scope of the question to delve into examining the differences between various RNGs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to seed `rand` with `srand`.  You also have code that will display a random number from 0 to 35, not 1 to 36.  This is because `%` returns the remainder of the operation, which will always be between 0 and divisor - 1.  So, your code should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    int a = 1 + rand() % 36;
    int b = 1 + rand() % 36;
    int c = 1 + rand() % 36;
    int d = 1 + rand() % 36;

    printf("1 = %d\n", a);
    printf("2 = %d\n", b);
    printf("3 = %d\n", c);
    printf("4 = %d\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```